# CoreLocation app working in Simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, core-location, jailbreak

I am trying to run this program on iPhone 3GS with iOS 5. Program works fine on simulator but doesn't work on device. No error but the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` delegate method doesn't get called when run on the device.

I just want to print location after every 30 seconds.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool
  {
    iLocation *loc = [[iLocation alloc] init];

    [loc start];

    NSLog(@"In main");

  }

  return 0;
}


@interface iLocation : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

-(void) start;
-(void) startAgain;

@end



#import "BIDAppDelegate.h"

@implementation iLocation

@synthesize locationManager;

-(void) start
{
  NSLog(@"Enter in start");

  locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  locationManager.delegate = self;

  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
  locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

  if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
  {
    NSLog(@"Location Services are enabled");

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
  }
  else
    NSLog(@"Location Services are disabled");


  NSLog(@"Exit from start");

}


-(void) startAgain
{
  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; 
}


- (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager
  didUpdateToLocation: (CLLocation *)newLocation
  fromLocation: (CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

  NSLog(@"Enter in didUpdateToLocation");

  NSString *latitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g\u00B0",
                              newLocation.coordinate.latitude];

  NSLog(@"Latitude = %@", latitudeString);


  NSString *longitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g\u00B0",
                               newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

  NSLog(@"Longitude = %@", longitudeString);


  NSString *horizontalAccuracyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%gm",
                                        newLocation.horizontalAccuracy];

  NSLog(@"Horizontal Accuracy = %@", horizontalAccuracyString);


  NSString *altitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%gm",
                              newLocation.altitude];

  NSLog(@"Altitude = %@", altitudeString);


  NSString *verticalAccuracyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%gm",
                                      newLocation.verticalAccuracy];

  NSLog(@"Vertical Accuracy = %@", verticalAccuracyString);


  NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:20.0
                                           target:self
                                         selector:@selector(startAgain)
                                         userInfo:nil
                                          repeats:YES];

  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer
                               forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];


  NSLog(@"Exit from didUpdateToLocation");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your Location service may be off in iPhone please on it and try again.

in iPhone->setting->Location Service set it ON.

Comment: iPhone Location Services are ON.

Comment: Please also add     locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
in your start method

Comment: No success after adding locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest in start method.

Comment: locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation method didn't get called even once when testing on device.

Comment: are you sure your start method call?

Comment: Yes, start method gets called after every 30 seconds.

Comment: In main, I have set the timer so that after every 30 minutes, start method gets called.

Comment: hello, may be in this case you have run loop problem please remove runloop and try again.

Comment: No success after removing run loop from main. In this case, it doesn't get called even once. This code works great with GUI but with console it doesn't work.

Comment: Please try this also instead NSTimer *timer.......  NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 
                        target:loc 
                      selector:@selector(start)
                      userInfo:alarm repeats:NO];

Comment: No success with your suggested NSTimer modification? Still, the same function didn't get called.

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

i think u have not initialized the date for today's date. And are u sure wether an app without a window or view, will be loaded into device..?

Comment: I am developing this program for jailbreak iPhone. And on jailbreak iPhone, program without a window is loaded.

Comment: here is my output: Still no success.

Enter in start
2012-02-06 15:47:52.346 WhereAmI[743:207] Location Services are enabled
2012-02-06 15:47:52.364 WhereAmI[743:207] Exit from start
2012-02-06 15:47:52.368 WhereAmI[743:207] In main
2012-02-06 15:47:52.374 WhereAmI[743:207] Still in main
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: There's no **technical** requirement for an app (that doesn't need App Store approval) to have a user interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a couple potential problems with the code posted.

First of all, I just commented about this on another question.  You don't need to keep telling `CLLocationManager` to `startUpdatingLocation`.  You can just make that call once, until you decide to tell it to `stopUpdatingLocation`.  Every time it gives you the new location, via

`locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation`

you save/use it.  You can have a timer fire every 30 seconds if you like, and if you don't have a newer location, then use the one from the last 30 seconds.  Or use `locationManager.location` to get the most recent location fix.

[See Apple's docs on CLLocationManager's startUpdatingLocation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)

> Calling this method several times in succession does not automatically
>   result in new events being generated. Calling stopUpdatingLocation in
>   between, however, does cause a new initial event to be sent the next
>   time you call this method.

Secondly, from the NSLog output you show above, and your `main` program, it looks like your program is just exiting before the location manager can ever deliver any location data.  I have a non-graphical jailbreak app that has a process that runs and uses CoreLocation, and my main program looks like this:

```
#import "LocationDaemon.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    LocationDaemon* daemon = [[LocationDaemon alloc] init];

    // start a timer so that the process does not exit.
    NSTimer* timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: [NSDate date]
                                              interval: 1.0
                                                target: daemon
                                              selector: @selector(run:)
                                              userInfo: nil
                                               repeats: NO];

    NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runLoop addTimer: timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [runLoop run];

    [daemon release];
    [pool release];
    [timer release];

    return 0;
}
```

It looks to me like you don't add your timer until after you receive location data, which you never get to before the program exits.  Try doing like I do above, and adding your timer earlier.  **I also call `[runLoop run]`, after adding my timer.**  I think you have to do that, to keep your main thread looping.  Your main program just calls `start`, which calls `startUpdatingLocation`, but those calls are not blocking.  Fairly quickly, it gets done with that, and the program completes.  I don't think having a retained `CLLocationManager` instance is enough to keep the program running.

I have no idea why it would work in the simulator, though :(

P.S.  Don't be concerned that my timer defined above does not repeat.  In the `run:` implementation, I believe it fires off another timer with a different interval, or selector. So, my program does in fact keep running.